# Fetch Comma Separated Multiple Binary Image in one row using Join In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**UserTable**

```
ID | Name |Code
---+------+-----
 1 | ABC  |ZADD
 2 | DGF  |TRTR
 3 | CDR  |HJIU   
 4 | QMD  |LOPR
```

**UserImagesTable**

```
IID | UserID |BinaryImg
---+--------+----- ---
 1 | 2      | 0X984597909
 2 | 2      | 0X334593393
 3 | 4      | 09845933543  
 4 | 4      | 0X379426937
 5 | 4      | 0X334589433
```

I am trying to fetch data from two tables using join, and join is working fine but it is duplicating FK id. I want to return user only one time but that user image multiple time that,s are against that UserId in UserImages table. I hope that it makes sense.

I have tried like this, but this query is not returning the expected result:

```
SELECT User.ID, User.Name, UserImage.BinaryImg 
FROM User 
INNER JOIN UserImages ON User.ID = UserImages.UserID
```

Expected result I want looks like this. I hope you understand and I am using SQL Server 2017

```
UID | Name | BinaryImg
----+------+--------------------------------------
 2  | DGF  | 0X984597909,0X334593393
 4  | QMD  | 0X379426937,0X334589433,09845933543
```

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem. Returning binary values back, as a delimited list (which means they aren't binary values anymore, they're a `varchar`), is just a bad idea. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: i want to return multiple images against a one User that are saved

Comment: Then return them as multiple rows, and then have the application iterate through the returned data set.

Comment: these are multiple rows but i want the on user data and  user multiple images in one row.

Comment: No, return multiple rows for a specific user as well. Don't delimit them, that is only going to make things harder, not easier.

Comment: Can you help me in this? And how should it be i am thankful to you :)

Comment: The query you have should already return the dataset you *really* need. Apart from that `USER` is a reserved word and so `FROM User` will error. I suggest fixing that my renaming your table `User` to something that isn't a reserved keyword.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222264/discussion-between-shakir-and-larnu).

Comment: I don't have any further to add here, I'm afraid, Shakir.

Answer (score 1):

Either of the following will produce the desired results...

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UserTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
     BEGIN DROP TABLE #UserTable; END;
     
     CREATE TABLE #UserTable (
        ID int NOT NULL,
        Name char(3) NOT NULL,
        Code char(4) NOT NULL 
        );
     INSERT #UserTable(ID, Name, Code) VALUES
     (1, 'ABC', 'ZADD'),
     (2, 'DGF', 'TRTR'),
     (3, 'CDR', 'HJIU'),   
     (4, 'QMD', 'LOPR');
    
     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UserImagesTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
     BEGIN DROP TABLE #UserImagesTable; END;
     
     CREATE TABLE #UserImagesTable (
        IID int NOT NULL,
        UserID int NOT NULL,
        BinaryImg binary(5) NOT NULL 
        );
     INSERT #UserImagesTable(IID, UserID, BinaryImg) VALUES
     (1, 2, 0x984597909),
     (2, 2, 0x334593393),
     (3, 4, 0x845933543),  
     (4, 4, 0x379426937),
     (5, 4, 0x334589433);
    
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
 -- Option 1...
 SELECT 
    ut.ID,
    ut.Name,
    img_array = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar(10), uit.BinaryImg, 1), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY uit.IID ASC)
 FROM
    #UserTable ut
    JOIN #UserImagesTable uit
        ON ut.ID = uit.UserID
GROUP BY
    ut.ID,
    ut.Name;

-- Option 2...
SELECT 
    ut.ID,
    ut.Name,
    i.img_array
FROM
    #UserTable ut
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            img_array = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar(10), uit.BinaryImg, 1), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY uit.IID ASC)
        FROM
            #UserImagesTable uit
        WHERE 
            ut.ID = uit.UserID
        GROUP BY
            uit.UserID
        ) i;
```

Results...

```
ID          Name img_array
----------- ---- ----------------------------------
2           DGF  0x09845979, 0x03345933
4           QMD  0x08459335, 0x03794269, 0x03345894


(1 row affected)
ID          Name img_array
----------- ---- ----------------------------------
2           DGF  0x09845979, 0x03345933
4           QMD  0x08459335, 0x03794269, 0x03345894
```

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is not a built in Function

Comment: @AsifShakir... You said you were using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Any solution Rather than `STRING_AGG` ?

Comment: Nothing as straight forward and easy as STRING_AGG()... but yea, FOR XML PATH('') works too. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: i am using Sql Server 2015